# Cannot declare 'MatRadioModule' when trying to compile angular library with angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I am creating an angular library with a few components that in turn uses angular material. I have added angular material to the angular project using `ng add @angular/material`. I also tried to add it to the library by using `ng add @angular/material --project webpay-components`. Adding it to the library project did not seem to do anything though.

When I run `ng build webpay-components`, I get the following output:

```
Building Angular Package
******************************************************************************
It is not recommended to publish Ivy libraries to NPM repositories.
Read more here: https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility
******************************************************************************

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'webpay-components'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: src/lib/webpay-components.module.ts:33:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'MatRadioModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

33     MatRadioModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/radio/radio-module.d.ts:11:22
    11 export declare class MatRadioModule {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'MatRadioModule' is declared here.
src/lib/webpay-components.module.ts:34:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'MatCheckboxModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

34     MatCheckboxModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/checkbox-module.d.ts:18:22
    18 export declare class MatCheckboxModule {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'MatCheckboxModule' is declared here.
src/lib/webpay-components.module.ts:35:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'MatIconModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

35     MatIconModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/icon/icon-module.d.ts:11:22
    11 export declare class MatIconModule {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'MatIconModule' is declared here.
```

and so on...

If I understand correctly, angular material is not a part of the library compilation. So my question is how I would add it so that angular material will be compiled with the library.

the package.json for the project containing the library looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "webpay-lib",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build-components": "ng build webpay-components"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^10.1.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

the package.json for the library project looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "webpay-components",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "webpay-provisioning": "file:../../dist/webpay-provisioning/webpay-provisioning-0.0.1.tgz"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ng build webpay-components",
    "pack": "cd ../../dist/webpay-components && npm pack",
    "deploy": "npm run build && npm run pack"
  }
}
```

And finally, the webpay-components.module.ts looks like the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormInputComponent } from './form-input/form-input.component';
import { AccountSettingsComponent } from './provision-settings/account-settings/account-settings.component';
import { CompanyInfoComponent } from './provision-settings/company-info/company-info.component';
import { ContactInfoComponent } from './provision-settings/contact-info/contact-info.component';
import { FeatureSettingsComponent } from './provision-settings/feature-settings/feature-settings.component';
import { IntegrationSettingsComponent } from './provision-settings/integration-settings/integration-settings.component';

import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FormInputComponent,
    CompanyInfoComponent,
    ContactInfoComponent,
    FeatureSettingsComponent,
    IntegrationSettingsComponent,
    AccountSettingsComponent,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    CompanyInfoComponent,
    ContactInfoComponent,
    FeatureSettingsComponent,
    IntegrationSettingsComponent,
    AccountSettingsComponent
  ]
})
export class WebpayComponentsModule { }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I'm just stupid! I added the Angular material modules to `declarations` instead of `imports`. The module should look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormInputComponent } from './form-input/form-input.component';
import { AccountSettingsComponent } from './provision-settings/account-settings/account-settings.component';
import { CompanyInfoComponent } from './provision-settings/company-info/company-info.component';
import { ContactInfoComponent } from './provision-settings/contact-info/contact-info.component';
import { FeatureSettingsComponent } from './provision-settings/feature-settings/feature-settings.component';
import { IntegrationSettingsComponent } from './provision-settings/integration-settings/integration-settings.component';

import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FormInputComponent,
    CompanyInfoComponent,
    ContactInfoComponent,
    FeatureSettingsComponent,
    IntegrationSettingsComponent,
    AccountSettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatInputModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CompanyInfoComponent,
    ContactInfoComponent,
    FeatureSettingsComponent,
    IntegrationSettingsComponent,
    AccountSettingsComponent
  ]
})
export class WebpayComponentsModule { }
```

Hopefully this could help anyone who makes a similar mistake.